# Diode IV experiment

Tags: electric-circuits, electrical-resistance, semiconductor-physics, batteries

Ive been looking at experiments to look at the IV relationship for a LED, but I see most of them use a rheostat instead of a series variable resistor and my question is, what is the advantage of using a rheostat over a variable resistor in this case?

[image]

Comment: Is a rheostat not a type of variable resistor? I'm confused by this question.

Comment: The rheostat is in parallel rather than being in series and I wasn't sure why.

Comment: Would [electronics.se] be a better home for this question?

Comment: @ACuriousMind Actually a rheostat can function as both: a variable resistor _or_ a fixed resistor. It depends on what terminals you wish to use. There are three of them if I'm not wrong. Connecting in one particular way gives a fixed resistance. But the way the diagram is drawn, it seems the rheostat is being used as a variable resistance.

Comment: @KunalPawar The arrangement in the diagram is a potential divider. Part of the voltage produced by the cell is across the left terminal and the sliding contact. If it has been used as a variable resistor then only two terminals would have been used with the device in series with the diode.

Comment: @Qmechanic I think that this is better off here as a question about a standard Physics experiment. The arrangement of the circuit is sometimes important and which depends on relative resistance values of the variable resistor /  potential divider and the component being tested.

Comment: @ACuriousMind A rheostat is a variable resistor with two terminals being used. The confusion is that the device which is called a rheostat usually has three terminals and by using all of those terminals it can be configured as a potential divider / potentiometer.

Answer (score 1):

There are devices which sometimes look like this and they are often called rheostats.

[image]

When terminals $C$ and $A$ or $B$ are being used it is probably being used as a variable resistor.
When all three terminals are being used is is probably being used as a potential divider / potentiometer.

So there are two possible arrangements which can be used to vary the current thorough and the voltage across a device.as shown below.

[image]

The left hand diagram is its use as a variable resistor and the current in the circuit is $I= \dfrac{\mathcal E}{R_{\rm D}+r}$.

This arrangement is not much use if $R_{\rm D} \gg r$ as changing $r$ does not change the current by very much.

The right-hand diagram varies the voltage across the device and works fine as long as $r \ll R_D$.
If this condition is not satisfied then the standard voltage divider equation $V_{\rm out} = \dfrac{r}{R+r}\mathcal E$ ceases to apply because the $r$ is in parallel with a much smaller resistor $R_{\rm D}$ and it is $R_{\rm D}$ which controls the output voltage.

The measurement of the $IV$ characteristics of a diode present a number of problems in that a diode behaves like a large value resistor when it is reverse biassed and  also below the knee voltage when it is forward biassed.
So in these regions the potential divider circuit is to be favoured.

However above the knee voltage the resistance of forward biassed diode is low and then the variable resistor arrangement is to be favoured to have good control of the currents flowing through the diode.

On top of this complication there the important consideration of the arrangement of the voltmeter and the ammeter.

If the diode resistance is low then the arrangement shown in the OP's diagram is a good one in that the voltmeter measures and voltage across the diode whilst the ammeter measures the current through the diode and the voltmeter which is effective the current through the diode because the resistance of the voltmeter is so much higher than that of the diode.

However when trying to measure the IV characteristic when the resistance of the diode is high the ammeter should be put in series with the diode to measure the current through the diode and the voltmeter should be placed across the diode and the ammeter to measure the voltage across the diode (and the very small voltage across the ammeter).

For "intermediate" values of diode resistance corrections might have to be made for the voltage drop across the ammeter and/or the current passing through the voltmeter.

Comment: just looking back at this and I don't understand why it works fine as long as $r \gg R_D$.  
If this condition is not satisfied then the standard voltage divider equation $V_{\rm out} = \dfrac{r}{R+r}\mathcal E$ ceases to apply as if a diode is used then it'll have a huge resistance at potential differences but works fine then

Comment: @Labracad I am sorry I got the inequality the wrong way round and have now corrected my answer. What you do not want is the diode to "load" the potential divider i.e. take a significant current from the potential divider circuit. The potential divider formula is derived on the assumption that both resistors which make up the potential divider have the same current passing through them which will not be the case if the diode has a relatively low resistance.

Comment: I dont think you can use the potential divider equation at all because the diode is in parallel with r so the voltage dropped needs to take into account the resistance of the parallel section with r and Rd

Comment: @Labracad If the diode resistance is high then the current through the diode is small compared with the current through the potential divider resistors so the potential divider formula will work. If $r = 10\, \Omega$ and $R_{\rm D}=10,000\,\Omega$ then the resistance of these two in parallel is $9.99\,\Omega$ which is not very different from $10\, \Omega$.

Answer (score 1):

As has been pointed out in the comments, a rheostat is a two-terminal adjustable resistor.

[image]

There is no rheostat in the circuit as drawn.

There is however, a potentiometer which is a three-terminal variable voltage divider (it is possible to connect a potentiometer to use as a rheostat but not the other way around).

[image]

The advantage that I see to the use of the potentiometer as drawn is that it is possible to adjust the voltage across to diode from zero volts (shuttle all the way to the left) up to the battery voltage (shuttle all the way to the right).

[Images Credit](http://www.resistorguide.com/rheostat/)